# LaTeX logo (\LaTeX)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to get the \LaTeX symbol to work in matplotlib.pyplot's mathtext or usetex (matplotlib==3.5.2).

Other symbols display correctly with `text_usetex` both `True` and `False`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
plt.plot([],[])
plt.title(r"$\alpha$")
plt.show()
```

however `\LaTeX` doesn't work with either:

```
plt.title(r"$\LaTeX$")
```

instead throwing, with `plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=True`:

```
Unknown symbol: \LaTeX, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

and with `plt.rcParams['text.usetex']=False`:

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$\\\\LaTeX$'
```

Comment: Why do you expect `\LaTeX` to work? It's not a [LaTeX: Symbol](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols). You didn't include the entire [Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Nk4.png), which ends with **ParseFatalException: Unknown symbol: \LaTeX, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! Frankly, to me, the text in bold wouldn't offer much more than what I quoted in the original post. In any case, you are correct, it appears not to be a Latex symbol. Is there any package or other dependency to be able to invoke it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\LaTeX` is a latex macro to be used in text mode, thus you have to remove the math mode `$...$` around it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.plot([],[])
plt.title(r"\LaTeX")
plt.show()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work without other packages. **RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found**, as such the answer is imcomplete.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney No other packages necessary, but obviously latex needs to be installed on the system if one wants to use latex.